# If Nexus-10 can't play more then 3 VideoView playing at the moment at screen - otherwise Nothing - Black View (files from SdCard)

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, nexus-10

Encountered the BIG problem with VideoView Nexus 10. Looks serious.

I wanted to create ListView with Videos that play simultaneously (with no sound). So problem: single VideoView plays but when there more then 3 (four VideoViews) play at the moment - nothing - black View (4th).

Even more ! **If you place Video at /sdcard/** After you encounter the problem NO MORE VIDEO (from SdCard) CAN BE PLAYED AT THE DEVICE AT ALL until reboot. Yep! **Other Application** can't play video from SdCard any more, too!